# problem rendering pages using react-router-dom getting warning msg: router.ts:11 No routes matched location "/charterdetails"

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to build application to make reservation for fishing charters for a school project I'm working on.  I'm using react-router-dom which works for the most part, but when I try and use a button to navigate to page it does not render components on 2 of the pages.  The page will refresh but it does not render the components "CharterDetails" or "BookCharter".

I get no errors but I do get a warning that says:

> No routes matched location "/charterdetails/62fb097cb985e11cb3884f6e"

It does not seem to matter if I use the button handler or just a link both options give the same result for both CharterDetails and BookCharter, navigation for other pages render as expected.

[Click here for my GitHub repository](https://github.com/rowens72/SCSFC/)
select the work-in-progress branch

hope I’m explaining clear enough.  Thank for your time

**App.js**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Nav from "./Components/Nav";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Components/Users/LoginForm";
import "./App.css";
import Landings from "./Pages/Landings.js";
import Boats from "./Pages/Boats";
import Charters from "./Pages/Charters";
import CharterDetails from "./Pages/CharterDetails";
import BookCharter from "./Pages/BookCharter";
import PageNotFound from "./Pages/404";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";

function App() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log("useParams", id);
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <img
          src="../assets/Images/scsfcBadge.png"
          alt="SoCal Sportfishing Club"
        />
        SoCal Sportfishing Club
      </header>
      <div className="main">
        <Router>
          <aside className="left">
            <Nav />
          </aside>
          <main>
            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/charters" element={<Charters />} />
              <Route path="/landings" element={<Landings />} />
              <Route path="/boats" element={<Boats />} />
              {/* need to add parameter :id to link */}
              <Route page="/bookcharter/" element={<BookCharter />} />
              {/* need to add parameter :id to link */}
              <Route page="/charterdetails/:id" element={<CharterDetails />} />
              <Route page="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
          <aside className="right">
            <Login />
          </aside>
        </Router>
      </div>
      <footer>Copyright © 2022 SoCal SportFishing Club </footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**:

```
import React,{useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,  Route, Routes, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Home(){

        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const [charterData, setCharterData] = useState([]);
        const [charterid, setCharterid] = useState('');
        useEffect(() => {
            // declare the async data fetching function
            const fetchData = async () => {
                fetch('http://localhost:5000/charter/featured/')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => setCharterData(data)); 
                console.log('Charter ', charterData)   
            }
          
            // call the function
            fetchData()
              // make sure to catch any error
              .catch(console.error);
          }, [])

          function handleClick(charter) {
            let id = charter.id;
            let path = `/charterdetails//${id}`
            navigate(path);
          }

          function BookClick(e) {
           // e.preventDefault();
            let path = `/bookcharter/${e.target.id}`
            navigate(path);
          }

    return(
        
            <div className="container">
            {
                    charterData.map((charter, index) => {
                      return(<div key={index} className="card">
                       <div className="card-header">
                      </div>
                           <img src={'../assets/Images/charters/' + charter.Img} alt={charter.CharterName} />
                            <div className="tag tag-teal">{charter.BoatName}&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;{charter.Duration}</div>
                               <div className="card-body">
                                  <div style={{fontSize:'28px', fontWeight: 'Bold'}}>
                                  {charter.CharterName}
                                  </div>
                                   <p style={{fontSize:'16px'}}>Departure date: {new Date(charter.Departure).toDateString()}<br />
                                   Return date: {new Date(charter.Return).toDateString()}<br />
                                   Trip Duration: {charter.Duration}<br />
                                   Price: ${charter.Cost}<br />
                                   Max Load:{charter.MaxLoad}<br />
                                   Target: {charter.Target}<br /></p>
                                   <div style={{textAlign:'center', width: '100%'}}>
                                    <Link
                                    to= {{
                                        pathname:`/charterdetails/${charter.id}`
                                    }}
                                    >
                                       <button>Details</button> 
                                    </Link>                                  
                                    <button onClick={BookClick}>Book</button>
                                </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>)
                  })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**Nav.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Nav() {
    return (
    <>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/landings">Landings</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/boats">Boats</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/charters">Club Charters</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/charterdetails">Charter Details</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/bookcharter">Book Charter</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
    </ul>
    </>
    );
  }
```

**CharterDetails.js**:

```
import React from 'react';

function CharterDetails(){
    return(
        <div>
            Charter Details
        </div>
    )
}

export default CharterDetails;
```

**BookCharter.js**:

```
import React from "react";

function BookCharter(){
    return(
       <>
        Book Charter
       </>
    )
}

export default BookCharter;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the app.js I had page instead of path on the route.

Changed from

```
<Route page="/bookcharter" element={<BookCharter />} />
<Route page="/charterdetails/:id" element={<CharterDetails />} />
```

to

```
  <Route exact path="/bookcharter" element={<BookCharter />} />
  <Route exact path="/charterdetails/:id" element={<CharterDetails />} />
```